# Java Apache Tomcat Required resource not found

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404

Im getting an error i dont know why. I have this project:

[image]

And when i execute registro.html  it works nicely:

[image]

But when i submit the post in the code i think it doesnt reach Registro.java

[image]

the code in registro.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Registro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost:8080/Ejer2/Registro.java" method="POST">
            <input type=hidden name=registro value=resultadoRegistro>
            <BR><BR>Username: <input type=text name=user>
            <BR><BR>Password: <input type=password name=pass>
            <BR><BR><input type=submit value="Enviar"><input type=reset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and in Registro.java this one:

```
    package Ejer2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.*;



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Registro extends HttpServlet implements SingleThreadModel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    public Registro() {
        super();

    }



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session=req.getSession(true);
        Usuario miuser=(Usuario)session.getValue(session.getId());
        if(miuser==null){
            miuser=new Usuario(req.getParameter("user"),req.getParameter("password"));
            session.putValue(session.getId(),miuser);
        }
        res.setContentType("text/html");

        String user=req.getParameter("user");
        //String pass = req.getParameter("pass");

        PrintWriter toClient = res.getWriter();
        toClient.println("<html>");
        toClient.println("<title>REGISTRO REALIZADO</title>");
        toClient.println("Usuario "+user+" registrado con exito");
        toClient.println("</html>");

        toClient.close();
    }

}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use or call like **`Registro.java` directly inside the html `action`** rather you need to map the url pattern for your `Registro` servlet class as shown below:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/Registro")
public class Registro extends HttpServlet implements SingleThreadModel{
   //Add your code here
}
```

Now use the above configured `urlPattern` as the `action` in your `registro.html`, shown below:

```
<form action="/Registro" method="POST">
```

Also, the other important point is that you don't need `SingleThreadModel` for the servlet classes in general (because all the requests will be served using the same servlet instance), but if you are using `SingleThreadModel` on purpose you can leave it as is.

Comment: When you say servlet class what file do you refer to?

Comment: I mean your `Registro` class

Comment: Ok so it says that WebServlet cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: You need `javax.servlet-api` jar with version 3.0 or higher

Comment: Could be the issue with the context path, so can you change the `action` in html to `/Ejer2/Registro` and try?